# single tab on uitextview when in edit mode, close keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextview

I want to close the keyboard, when a user do a single tap on `uitextview` and when he is in edit mode. Does anyone know how to do that?

`touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is not fired.
I can't use the `textViewDidBeginEditing` though.

Have included `UITextViewDelegate` in my header file. In *.m file*, I have set the delegate as `self.textView.delegate = self` and below is the code to capture touch event

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; 
    if([self.textView isFirstResponder]) 
    { 
        [self.textView resignFirstResponder]; 
    } 
}
```

But it is not getting called by the textView I am using.

Comment: I assume you talk about objective-C on an iPhone? And which code have you tried, where do you struggle?

Comment: Have included UITextViewDelegate in my header file.

In .m file,

I have set the delegate as self.textView.delegate = self and below is the code to capture touch event

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if([self.textView isFirstResponder])
    {
        [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

But it is not getting called by the textView I am using.. What could be the reason?

Comment: This time I did it for you, but next time please: use the "edit" button under your question to add all relevant and new data/ code/ information. As far as I see, there must be more code you use, because you have some variables mentioned that are not inside your given code.

Answer (score 0):

When using Pinch and touch events you have to initialize the touch event. I can't remember of the top of my head but it is something like

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
 tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

put this in your viewDidLoad and then touchesBegan should get called when you tap the screen, Oh don't forget to add the (tapGesture) to the view like so

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Hope this helps.